# double.parse System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to programming and have been racking my brains out trying to fix this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
string sBipLength = aPart.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PART_LENGTH).AsValueString();
double dParse2 = Double.Parse(sBipLength);
sBipLength = (dParse2 / aPart.CenterlineLength).ToString();
```

I am wanting to return the `AsValueString` and convert it to a format to where i can divide.

Comment: What does the string look like?

Comment: Have you debugged and checked the value of `sBipLength`?

Comment: What is the value of `sBipLength `?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd set a breakpoint at the first line, and step through (hit F10). Then hover over `sBitLength` to see what the value is that you're getting. I'm supposing that what you're getting isn't a valid double.

Also, it's generally recommended that you use `Double.TryParse` if you don't know for certain what the format will be. (This isn't always the case, but `TryParse` is safer.)

```
string sBipLength = aPart.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FABRICATION_PART_LENGTH).AsValueString();

double dParse2 = 0;
if(!Double.TryParse(sBipLength, out dParse2))//syntax edit 
{ 
    // handle any errors here when applicable
}
else 
{
    sBipLength = (dParse2 / aPart.CenterlineLength).ToString();
}
```

There are a lot of different ways you could structure the `TryParse` block, and you'll probably have to make modifications to fit it into your current code. This is just an example of it in action. (Important note: the `out` keyword sort of acts as another `return` in a sense. `Double.TryParse` returns a `bool`, but that `out` gives you the double assuming the string is valid.)